# Power adapter for handheld sewing machine

Tags: power-supply

I have a handheld sewing machine which requires 4 AA batteries or a 6v, 800ma power adapter. I intend to use this sewing machine on power adapter but I only have a 6v, 300ma power adapter. Can I use this power adapter to run the sewing machine without the danger of overheating or exploding the adapter? If I can, should I expect any decrease in performance on the sewing machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Not only will the adapter heat but also the device may not work properly.

This is because the power needed by the device is not provided. you gave it 6V 300mA instead of 6V 800mA. IF the device wants to draw 800mA, the adapter will be in danger.

Comment: You mean "no" to his 1st question, and "yes" to his 2nd :-)

Comment: Yes. I mean what you said.